# window.open is not working in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager

Hi my below code is as below

```
public void OpenNewWindow(string url)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, this.GetType(), "newindow", String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}');</script>", url), true);
}
```

my url is passing as

```
OpenNewWindow("www.abc/Print/XMLGenerate.aspx?orders=3571,6548,12365");
```

It is giving an error as

```
VM2057:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Sys$_ScriptLoader$_loadScriptsInternal [as _loadScriptsInternal] (ScriptResource.axd?d=_8_35uBVZ-S2jnBttGVmnHcbGwsk1nM64gRJtmlHHewS3NkHUVKLyALoy79wOJSTQl657BexO1752uv8bgOrPs9tLBJeYB4N7IpugWjIKRoH86P9uHvQj8d2Xm-FYk7R7hNQm09O40zoSBJZyKjkTtAYANuVNh1EOKGdqJWFGJQZm_rb0&t=636147379983068386:3286)
    at Sys$_ScriptLoader$_loadScriptsInternal [as _loadScriptsInternal] (ScriptResource.axd?d=_8_35uBVZ-S2jnBttGVmnHcbGwsk1nM64gRJtmlHHewS3NkHUVKLyALoy79wOJSTQl657BexO1752uv8bgOrPs9tLBJeYB4N7IpugWjIKRoH86P9uHvQj8d2Xm-FYk7R7hNQm09O40zoSBJZyKjkTtAYANuVNh1EOKGdqJWFGJQZm_rb0&t=636147379983068386:3290)
    at Sys$_ScriptLoader$loadScripts [as loadScripts] (ScriptResource.axd?d=_8_35uBVZ-S2jnBttGVmnHcbGwsk1nM64gRJtmlHHewS3NkHUVKLyALoy79wOJSTQl657BexO1752uv8bgOrPs9tLBJeYB4N7IpugWjIKRoH86P9uHvQj8d2Xm-FYk7R7hNQm09O40zoSBJZyKjkTtAYANuVNh1EOKGdqJWFGJQZm_rb0&t=636147379983068386:3198)
    at Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmitCompleted [as _onFormSubmitCompleted] (ScriptResource.axd?d=MS2pc9Tcsbrxuj1VKAktXocj4F9LLMsEyyz5ZnCns74XPDoBm5VLVPwiAP7SDISdDcLXnFYsvAQ0PHmXuj9GwXnoGgS40UHyiv2B9ttDr5POSDTSShhb5bCVbV5jmN7Ows0Wse3j_8tPFzB47qe7jC0j2l8yMjf18limZg3b3hmfpECE0&t=636147379983068386:1177)
    at Array.<anonymous> (ScriptResource.axd?d=_8_35uBVZ-S2jnBttGVmnHcbGwsk1nM64gRJtmlHHewS3NkHUVKLyALoy79wOJSTQl657BexO1752uv8bgOrPs9tLBJeYB4N7IpugWjIKRoH86P9uHvQj8d2Xm-FYk7R7hNQm09O40zoSBJZyKjkTtAYANuVNh1EOKGdqJWFGJQZm_rb0&t=636147379983068386:50)
    at Sys$EventHandlerList$getHandler.evt._handler (ScriptResource.axd?d=_8_35uBVZ-S2jnBttGVmnHcbGwsk1nM64gRJtmlHHewS3NkHUVKLyALoy79wOJSTQl657BexO1752uv8bgOrPs9tLBJeYB4N7IpugWjIKRoH86P9uHvQj8d2Xm-FYk7R7hNQm09O40zoSBJZyKjkTtAYANuVNh1EOKGdqJWFGJQZm_rb0&t=636147379983068386:2503)
    at Sys$Net$WebRequest$completed [as completed] (ScriptResource.axd?d=_8_35uBVZ-S2jnBttGVmnHcbGwsk1nM64gRJtmlHHewS3NkHUVKLyALoy79wOJSTQl657BexO1752uv8bgOrPs9tLBJeYB4N7IpugWjIKRoH86P9uHvQj8d2Xm-FYk7R7hNQm09O40zoSBJZyKjkTtAYANuVNh1EOKGdqJWFGJQZm_rb0&t=636147379983068386:4458)
    at XMLHttpRequest.Sys$Net$XMLHttpExecutor._onReadyStateChange (ScriptResource.axd?d=_8_35uBVZ-S2jnBttGVmnHcbGwsk1nM64gRJtmlHHewS3NkHUVKLyALoy79wOJSTQl657BexO1752uv8bgOrPs9tLBJeYB4N7IpugWjIKRoH86P9uHvQj8d2Xm-FYk7R7hNQm09O40zoSBJZyKjkTtAYANuVNh1EOKGdqJWFGJQZm_rb0&t=636147379983068386:4009)
```

What I am trying to is opening this url as new tab on button click

Comment: The last `true` argument causes the addition of `<script></script>` so you have two sets, remove yours.

Comment: @AlexK. so I have to remove true?

Comment: @EdPlunkett added the error

Comment: Personally I would remove them from the string.

Comment: @MiteshJain Thanks!

Comment: @AlexK. thanks it is being resolved.